# How to invoke Spring BeanPostProcessor within HK2

Tags: spring, jersey, jersey-2.0, hk2

I have a Jersey 2 application using the jersey-spring bridge. However, it seems that `BeanPostProcessors` declared in my application context are never invoked on resources created by Jersey (which actually delegates all this to HK2). I think that the Jersey-Spring bridge only care about resources annotated with `@Component` and fields annotated with `@Autowired`.

I was wondering how I could actually automatically invoke BeanPostProcessor's on newly created Jersey resources.

I found that there was an `InstanceLifecycleListener` but I was unable to find any documentation on this can be used.

Comment: Any reason for down-voting this question? If it requires improvement in some way, I would be more than happy to do that, but I honestly don't know how I can improve it now? Any advices are welcomed.